# Migrate content profile:Failing with source plugin exception

Tags: 7, migrations

I am struggling with setting up a migration from a Drupal 6 site to a Drupal 7 site. The Drupal 6 site used [Content Profile](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_profile) nodes to store some user information that in the new site will be fields attached to the user account. I am using the [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) module along with [migrate_d2d](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d). I have tried setting up with the migrate_d2d UI as well as writing a custom module to define the migration based off the migrate_d2d example.

Migration failed with source plugin exception:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'f.field_profile_other_value' in 'field list', in
>   includes/database/database.inc:2170

This `field_profile_other` is one of the content_profile fields in the D6 site. I checked the database the column in the error message is present and has data in it. I doesn't matter what I map this field to, I get the same error every time. I have tried marking the field not to be mapped to no avail.

The migrate_d2d code has functions in it that deal with content_profile data, so it appears to be something it is prepared to migrate. I am a loss as to proceed. Any help would be much appreciated.